# Eclipse compiler with APT

Tags: java, apt

What is the correct way to call the Eclipse compiler with an APT processor from Java?

I am using the following Maven dependency for the compiler

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
  <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I want to test an APT processor with the Eclipse compiler in addition to Javac.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using a custom builder.
Right click project -> properties -> builders 
setup a new one that uses apt

Answer (score 0):

AndroidAnnotations is a framework that generates java code based on annotations using APT.

This framework uses Maven as the default build environnement and have documentation on how to integrate AndroidAnnotations onto a maven based project.

I think you will find all what you need by looking the code.

You could have a look to :
* The presentation page : http://androidannotations.org/
* The github repository : https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations